# AWS Lambda Layers - module 'dicttoxml' has no attribute 'dicttoxml'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a AWS Lambda function based on python 3.7 and trying to use a module [dicttoxml](https://pypi.org/project/dicttoxml/) via AWS layers. My Python code is as below:

```
import json
import dicttoxml
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml({"name": "Foo"})
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

At my local machine, it works perfectly fine but Lambda gives error as below:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "module 'dicttoxml' has no attribute 'dicttoxml'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 4, in lambda_handler\n    xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml({\"name\": \"Ankur\"})\n"
  ]
}
```

The [directory structure](https://gofile.io/d/63wc4i) of dicttoxml layer is as below:

> dicttoxml.zip > python > dicttoxml > dicttoxml.py

I feel puzzled, what is wrong here?

Comment: How did you create the layer? Seems its malformed.

Comment: Yes I created layer and attached to the function

Answer (score 1):

I  created the custom layer with `dicttoxml` can **confirm that it works**.

The technique used includes **docker tool** described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

Thus for this question, I **verified it**  as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
echo dicttoxml > ./requirements.txt
```

3. Run the following docker command:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.7" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Create layer as zip:

```
zip -9 -r mylayer.zip python
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.7`.
6. Test the layer in lambda using the following lambda function:

```
import dicttoxml

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(dir(dicttoxml))
```

The function executes correctly:

```
['LOG', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'collections', 'convert', 'convert_bool', 'convert_dict', 'convert_kv', 'convert_list', 'convert_none', 'default_item_func', 'dicttoxml', 'escape_xml', 'get_unique_id', 'get_xml_type', 'ids', 'key_is_valid_xml', 'logging', 'long', 'make_attrstring', 'make_id', 'make_valid_xml_name', 'numbers', 'parseString', 'randint', 'set_debug', 'unicode', 'unicode_literals', 'unicode_me', 'version', 'wrap_cdata']
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, I was using wrong directory structure.